# ActionBarSherlock classic menu style

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0 with min api 7 and target api 17.

When I test the menu on an api 7 device, the bottom menu appears to be very poor formatted.
I tried to change it, but all I could do is to change the background color with:

```
<item name="android:panelFullBackground">@color/menu_background_color</item>
```

I would like to show it the same way the not overflown menu items: with white text color.